# Linq & ASP.NET MVC: how to use "or" and "equals" in join statement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

How to translate this sql query in a linq query, please?

```
USE [BiblioDB]
 GO
 SELECT *
   FROM Exemplaire e
    LEFT JOIN location l
    ON e.ExemplaireId = l.ExemplaireId
    INNER JOIN Retour r
    ON l.LocationId is null or l.LocationId = r.LocationId
 Go
```

I tried this linq query but the fourth line doesn't work.

```
 BiblioDBContext biblioDBContext = new BiblioDBContext();
 var query = from e in biblioDBContext.Exemplaires
           join l in biblioDBContext.Locations on e.ExemplaireId equals l.LocationId
           join r in biblioDBContext.Retours on l.LocationId == null || l.LocationId equals r.LocationId r.LocationId
 select e;
```

Comment: Error: Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'

Comment: We don't have type information for your types or all the information we need to solve your issue; plus when a user has given you an answer, you say, "I get 15 errors" without editing your question with the precise errors you get. I'm not sure how you expect us to help you without giving us all the information we need to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 BiblioDBContext biblioDBContext = new BiblioDBContext();
 var query = from e in biblioDBContext.Exemplaires
     join l in biblioDBContext.Locations on e.ExemplaireId equals l.ExemplaireId into el
     from l in el.DefaultIfEmpty()
     from r in biblioDBContext.Retours
     where (l.LocationId == null) || (l.LocationId.Equals(r.LocationId))
 select new {e, l, r};
```

The issue is the missing `DefaultIfEmpty()` clause that is needed for Left Joins.

Comment: @Sounouk What errors do you get? How do you expect us to help you if you don't give us the feedback we need to solve your issue?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Is it working now? If not, please, post the error message.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, I tried to add the error messages but I couldn't, there were more characters than authorized. Sorry!

Comment: @Zanon, thank you! the code works but there are no value returned, I commented the line "where l.LocationId == null" for testing and the sytem returned the values of the "Retours" table. Here is an exemple of expected return values: Exemplaire = {e1, e2, e3} ; Location = {e2, e3} ; Retour = {e2} ... The System should return: e1, e2

Comment: @Sounouk, I've edited again. Your OR operator can't be placed in Linq Join, so I had to use another from (SelectMany) and the OR operator in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Sounouk it should be edited into your question, not as a comment.